# Custom Integration in Trengo

Tags: javascript, automation, webhooks

Is it possible to hook our own custom AI model to the Trengo Flowbot? Or use any of their APIs/webhooks to achieve the same?
The chat widget is already provided by Trengo, but we need to integrate our own responses into it from an in-house generated AI model